# Parsing an array Json to select Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have a Json response. I need to take each value and append them to the Select tag. Each value separated by comma should be appended as a option in select tag.

Code is :

Jquery:

```
var dec ={"dc":["One","Two","Three"]};

jQuery.each(dec, function(index, value) {

    $(".request").append("<option value='" + index + "'>" + value + "</option>");  

});
```

HTML:

```
<select class="request">

</select>
```

The above code is appending everything to a single option but not as different options in select tag

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
var dec ={"dc":["One","Two","Three"]};
var html = "";
jQuery.each(dec, function(index, value) {

    html += "<option value='" + index + "'>" + value + "</option>";  
});

 $(".request").html( html );
```

Comment: This code won't work.  It results in the exact problem the OP is having.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the `dc` array.  Right now you have an object, `dec` with a child array `dc`.

```
jQuery.each(dec.dc, function(index, value) {
    $(".request").append("<option value='" + index + "'>" + value + "</option>");  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $opt;

For (var i = 0; i < dec.dc.length; i++) {
    $opt = $('<option></option>');
    $opt.text(dec.dc[i]);
    $opt.val(i);
    $('.request').append($opt);
}
```

Do a basic js loop when you can, they're faster.